# Select random rows without repeating

Tags: mysql

I need to select random rows without repeating, I am using the code below but receive a warning:

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result
```

Please help

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "raffle";
$password = "raffle";
$dbname = "raffle";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//code you provided
$sql = "select staff_id, staff_name from 
(select DISTINCT  staff_id, staff_name from dbo.[staff]) 
as derived1 ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "$row[staff_id]", "$row[staff_name]";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "none";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

please run this code and check

Answer (score 0):

**LIMIT** is your friend. TOP 1 is not in MySQL only MSSQL. so change the query to LIMIT 1 like:

```
$sql = "select staff_id, staff_name from 
 (select DISTINCT  staff_id, staff_name from dbo.[staff]) 
 as derived1 ORDER BY RAND() 
 LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: thanks a lot but the warning still exists, i used the query you provided and getting none

Comment: @user1873058 - sorry i have not seen, you also must change **NEWID()** to **RAND()**

Comment: no worries, still same, could you please check my code (edited the previous)